# How can i reduce execution time of my query

Tags: postgresql

I have a sum query that takes a long time to give the result, for about 40 seconds. Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    id_article, 
    sum(qte) as total 
FROM 
    Mouvstk
WHERE 
    date >= '20180609'
GROUP BY 
    id_article
```

I've created an index on id_article and another one on date. There are about 16 millions rows.

when i run explain analyze verbose i get this result:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=440073.16..443607.99 rows=6779 width=40) (actual time=25504.816..25562.865 rows=14142 loops=1)
  Output: id_article, sum(qte)
  Group Key: mouvstk.id_article
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=440073.16..443319.89 rows=27116 width=40) (actual time=25504.799..25580.712 rows=63081 loops=1)
        Output: id_article, (PARTIAL sum(qte))
        Workers Planned: 4
        Workers Launched: 4
        ->  Sort  (cost=439073.10..439090.05 rows=6779 width=40) (actual time=25446.155..25447.759 rows=12616 loops=5)
              Output: id_article, (PARTIAL sum(qte))
              Sort Key: mouvstk.id_article
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1434kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1431kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1428kB
              Worker 2:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1430kB
              Worker 3:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1430kB
              Worker 0: actual time=25433.322..25434.870 rows=12618 loops=1
              Worker 1: actual time=25435.450..25437.032 rows=12599 loops=1
              Worker 2: actual time=25427.157..25428.702 rows=12611 loops=1
              Worker 3: actual time=25432.809..25434.284 rows=12599 loops=1
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=438556.99..438641.73 rows=6779 width=40) (actual time=25432.515..25441.923 rows=12616 loops=5)
                    Output: id_article, PARTIAL sum(qte)
                    Group Key: mouvstk.id_article
                    Worker 0: actual time=25417.656..25428.424 rows=12618 loops=1
                    Worker 1: actual time=25424.587..25432.008 rows=12599 loops=1
                    Worker 2: actual time=25416.391..25423.729 rows=12611 loops=1
                    Worker 3: actual time=25417.598..25428.208 rows=12599 loops=1
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.mouvstk  (cost=0.00..429549.32 rows=1801535 width=13) (actual time=454.411..24611.221 rows=1439376 loops=5)
                          Output: code_origine, numero_caisse, numero_document, date, code_clifour, code_vendeur, code_affaire, code_magasin, numero_serie, libelle, puht, puhtnet, puttc, puttcnet, taux_remise, code_tva, taux_tva, code_devise, parite_devise, frais_approche, prht, nomenclature, type_vente, code_tarif, code_categorie_achat, numero_lot, date_peremption, pvttcstd, lib_tarif, id_ligne_document, id, id_article, qte, id_clifour
                          Filter: (mouvstk.date >= '2018-06-09'::date)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1791877
                          Worker 0: actual time=438.619..24600.391 rows=1428362 loops=1
                          Worker 1: actual time=445.653..24609.448 rows=1425821 loops=1
                          Worker 2: actual time=437.424..24600.521 rows=1430897 loops=1
                          Worker 3: actual time=438.652..24605.422 rows=1430127 loops=1
Planning Time: 0.356 ms
Execution Time: 25624.787 ms
```

Can someone explain to me why the query is so long and help me to reduce this execution time ?

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following compound index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON Mouvstk (date, id_article, qte);
```

Including the `date` will allow Postgres to filter off records earlier than June 9th, 2018.  Then, for what remains of the B tree, Postgres may aggregate all records belonging to a given article in order, by simply scanning the index once.  Note that I also include `qte` at the end of the index, to avoid the need to seek back to the main table to find this value.  This index is said to completely *cover* your query.

Make sure you `VACUUM` the table to get efficient index-only scans.

Comment: It works perfectly. I now get the result in 4 seconds. Thanks a lot.